# Is it acceptable to set global variables inside a function in Python?

Tags: python, global-variables

I want to write a python program. My code looks like this

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
   a,b = ParseArgs() # this is my function which uses argparse lib
   n = 30
   x = np.random.randint(20)
   do_sth(a,b) # this function uses n and x inside its definition
```

I'm wondering if I could do sth like this:

```py
def setup():
    a,b = ParseArgs() # this is my function which uses argparse lib
    n = 30
    x = np.random.randint(20)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   setup()
   do_sth(a,b) # this function uses n and x inside its definition
```

so that code looks more clear (note that in my real code setup part is much longer). I suppose that I can't do it, first of all because `do_sth` uses `x` and `n`. But what if I just change `do_sth` so that it takes `x` and `n` as arguments? Would it then be a good idea to put lines that create some global variables in `setup` function?

Comment: Please consider to use ``return x, n`` in ``setup()``. Then you can do: ``a, b = setup(); do_sth(a,b)`` - no need for global variables at all. (``;`` only used to write the code in one line, please don't do this in your app). Also: [Are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)

Comment: @MikeScotty thanks, 1.I like the idea of returning from setup 2.I'd been confused about global variables (I used to think they shouldn't be used at all, but then I saw some global vars in code in my job written by more experienced programmers) - but now thanks  to answers to the question you linked I think I understand it finally :)

Comment: Even more experienced programmers sometimes are just lazy - the bad lazy. As a rule of thumb: stick to your belief that global variables shouldn't be used at all. There are some very good exceptions to that rule - but they really are exceptions. When in doubt: dont use globals.